# SQLAlchemy: Keep the session's connection when rolling back

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I would like to implement a MySQL style named lock like in http://arr.gr/blog/2016/05/mysql-named-locks-in-python-context-managers/ :

Using sqlalchemy Session, I directly execute a GET_LOCK:

```
lock = session.execute("SELECT GET_LOCK('TEST', 5)")
```

Then if my lock is OK, I do what I want, especially some stuff with my database using the session. After that I release the lock:

```
session.execute("SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('TEST)")
```

My question is the following:
How can I be sure that the session connection to the database for the release is the same as the one at the beginning ?

The sqlalchemy's documentation says:

> When the transactional state is completed after a rollback or commit,
> the Session releases all Transaction and Connection resources [...]
>
> http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html

I'm in the context of a web application, so every time the session is committed, or if the session is rollbacked, the next queries aren't guaranteed to be on the same connection. For most of my operations, that isn't a problem, but in the case of a MySQL named lock, 'GET_LOCK' and 'RELEASE_LOCK' have to be requested on the same connection.

The only way I found is to have a specific session for the locking : it will keep its connection only for the lock. But is there a way not to use a connection just for this purpose ?

**Edit 2017-06-22**:

This topic is about the same subject: [SQLAlchemy session and connection relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35594706/sqlalchemy-session-and-connection-relationship). But if a scoped_session is used:

- Regarding the extract from the documentation above, after a commit or a rollback, the connection for future queries with this session may be different, right ?
- A unique session will be used in the thread ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that could help someone else, finally I used a scoped_session with a bind when getting the session for the first time in a request:

```
# Initialization:
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

# ...

# Before processing a request:
connection = engine.connect()
Session(bind=connection)

# ...

# After the processing
Session.remove()
connection.close()
```

With this configuration, if during my request processing I use GET_LOCK/RELEASE_LOCK, they will apply on the same connection.